# MultichoiceField in ModelForm for Django with DB relations

Tags: javascript, python, django

This is my first post ever on Stackoverflow so please ignore mistakes. Before posting I had tried a dozen solutions bun none worked. I have table relations in models for users. I need to create a ModelForm to let customer select multiple users for any project from the frontend. I am having hard time implementing it in code. Also for another field I need to limit the choice to one user. Following is the code.

Models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
   project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(User)
   project_url = models.URLField()

def __init__(self):
    return str(self.project_name)
```

Form.

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm)
     class Meta:
       fields = ['project_name', 'assigned_to ', 'project_url']
```

View:

```
def projects(request):
   template = 'projects/projects.html'
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
   else:
     form = ProjectForm()
   return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

HTML:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form }}
 <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Some help is highly appreciated.

Comment: When I was in a situation like this I had a list of users with checkbox. On submit I had an post request send the list of users and in the views.py I would get the list from request.POST while overriding the post method and then loop through that list and add the users pk .. something like
```
    for pk in selected:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
                    project.project_users.add(user)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    continue
         
    ```
Don't know if this is the method your looking for

Comment: Nice solution but I have precise goal to achieve it something like selecting "Tags" at StackOverFlow when we add question. But for starter list is enough and I will add autocomplete later myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        assigned_users = kwargs.pop('assigned_to', [])
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs = {"class": "form-control"}
        self.fields['project_name'].required = True
        self.fields['project_url'].required = True

        if assigned_users:
            self.fields['assigned_to'].queryset = assigned_users
        self.fields['assigned_to'].required = True

        self.fields['project_name'].widget.attrs.update({
            'placeholder': 'Project Name'})
        self.fields['project_url'].widget.attrs.update({
            'placeholder': 'Project URL'})
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('project_name', 'project_url', 'assigned_to')
```

views.py

```
def create_project(request):
    template_name = "create.html"
    users = []

    form = ProjectForm(assigned_to=users)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES, assigned_to=users)
        if form.is_valid():
            proj_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            proj_obj.created_by = request.user
            proj_obj.save()

            if request.POST.getlist('assigned_to', []):
                proj_obj.assigned_to.add(*request.POST.getlist('assigned_to'))
                assigned_to_list = request.POST.getlist('assigned_to')
            success_url = reverse('projects:list')
            if request.POST.get("savenewform"):
                success_url = reverse("leads:add_lead")
            return JsonResponse({'error': False, 'success_url': success_url})
        return JsonResponse({'error': True, 'errors': form.errors})
    context = {}
    context["proj_form"] = form
    context["users"] = users

    context["assignedto_list"] = [
        int(i) for i in request.POST.getlist('assigned_to', []) if i]

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

create.html:

```
<div class="form-control">
    {{ proj_form.project_name }}
    {{ proj_form.assigned_to }}
    {{ proj_form.project_url }}

</div>
```

Comment: Wow man bulls eye. Thank you so much I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I edited my own code something I was working on. Ignore the JSON part in view I was in rush.